# Nginx with memcache, gunzip and ssi don't working together

Tags: nginx, memcached, ssi

I'm trying to save packed (gzip) html in Memcached and use in from nginx:

1. load html from memcached by [memcached module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_memcached_module.html)
2. unpack by nginx [gunzip module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gunzip_module.html) if packed
3. process ssi insertions by [ssi module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html)
4. return result to user

mostly, configuration works, except ssi step:

```
  location / {
    ssi on;
    set $memcached_key "$uri?$args";
    memcached_pass memcached.up;
    memcached_gzip_flag 2; #  net.spy.memcached use second byte for compression flag
    default_type text/html;
    charset utf-8;
    gunzip on;
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "gzip";
    error_page  404 405 400 500 502 503 504 = @fallback;
  }
```

Looks like, nginx do ssi processing before unpacking by gunzip module.

In result HTML I see unresolved ssi instructions:

```
<!--# include virtual="/remote/body?argument=value" -->
```

No errors in the nginx log.

Have tried **ssi_types ***  -- no effect

Any idea how to fix it?

nginx 1.10.3 (Ubuntu)

**UPDATE**

Have tried with one more upstream. Same result =(

In the log, I see, ssi filter applied after upstream request, but without detected includes.

```
upstream memcached {
  server localhost:11211;
  keepalive 100;
}

upstream unmemcached {
  server localhost:21211;
  keepalive 100;
}

server {
  server_name dev.me;
  ssi_silent_errors off;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/error1.log debug;    log_subrequest  on;
  location / {
    ssi on;
    ssi_types *;
    proxy_pass http://unmemcached;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
  }

  location @fallback {
    ssi on;
    proxy_pass http://proxy.site;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    error_page 400 500 502 503 504  /offline.html;
  }
}

server {
  access_log  on;
  listen 21211;
  server_name unmemcached;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/error2.log debug;    log_subrequest  on;

  location / {
    set $memcached_key "$uri?$args";
    memcached_pass memcached;
    memcached_gzip_flag 2;
    default_type text/html;
    charset utf-8;
    gunzip on;
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "gzip";
    error_page  404 405 400 500 502 503 504 = @fallback;
  }

  location @fallback {
    #ssi on;
    proxy_pass http://proxy.site;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    error_page 400 500 502 503 504  /offline.html;
  }

}
```

I want to avoid solution with dynamic nginx modules if possible

Comment: Can you first remove caching from config and see if it works or not? You should solve issues by using one layer at a time

Comment: Without caching or without gzip everything works well. But I need gziped cache with ssi =)

Comment: See if this helps ? https://serverfault.com/questions/322109/nginx-proxy-caching-and-ssi

Comment: I have already seen it. caching with ssi works fine

Comment: @demon101 what happens if you clear all the caches, and then request the page w/ [curl](http://mdoc.su/n/curl), without using any higher-level UA?

Comment: @cnst I check with wget. What kind of cache should I clear?

Comment: @demon101 please use `curl -v` specifically, as `wget` seems to be more opaque.  Just make sure the cache on the nginx side is cleared, but you can even try it without clearing first to see if the issue is no longer reproducible w/ `gunzip on`.

Comment: @cnst w/o gunzip (and gzip in memcached add) everifing works well. Thousands of users testing it on production server

Comment: @demon101, i don't understand your comment. if it works well without `gunzip on`, what exactly is the problem?!  i think it's possible that gunzip doesn't actually gunzip your memcache data if the client itself requests gzip'ed content, hence, try to see what you get directly w/ curl.

Comment: @cnst problem in SSI. it not applied. I'm usung ssi for user-specific header-menu. With enabled compression in memcached user see page well, bug without inserted via ssi menu.

Comment: @demon101, but you provide very little troubleshooting details on why it doesn't work.  There is no magic, SSI obviously doesn't have gzip support, so, you first gotta understand and determine whether `gunzip on` works properly, and which way you gotta dig deeper; hence my suggestion to use `curl -v` to troubleshoot.

Comment: @cnst I got. You mean, nginx can return gziped content without unzip-zip in between. Ok. will check.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two issues to consider — whether the order of the filter modules is appropriate, and whether gunzip works for your situation.

## 0. The order of gunzip/ssi/gzip.

A simple [search for "nginx order of filter modules"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=nginx+order+of+filter+modules&t=ffab&ia=web) reveals that the order is determined at the compile time based on the content of the [`auto/modules`](http://ngx.su/auto/modules) shell script:

- http://www.evanmiller.org/nginx-modules-guide.html

  > Multiple filters can hook into each location, so that (for example) a response can be compressed and then chunked. The order of their execution is determined at compile-time. Filters have the classic "CHAIN OF RESPONSIBILITY" design pattern: one filter is called, does its work, and then calls the next filter, until the final filter is called, and Nginx finishes up the response.
- https://allthingstechnical-rv.blogspot.de/2014/07/order-of-execution-of-nginx-filter.html

  > The order of filters is derived from the order of execution of nginx modules. The order of execution of nginx modules is implemented within the file auto/modules in the nginx source code.

A quick glance at [`auto/modules`](http://ngx.su/auto/modules) reveals that `ssi` is between `gzip` and `gunzip`, however, it's not immediately clear which way the modules get executed (top to bottom or bottom to top), so, the default might either be reasonable, or, you may need to switch the two (which wouldn't necessarily be supported, IMHO).

One hint here is the location of the `http_not_modified` filter, which is given as an example of the `If-Modified-Since` handling on EMiller's guide above; I would imagine that it has to go last, after all the other ones, and, if so, then, indeed, it seems that the order of gunzip/ssi/gzip is exactly the opposite of what you need.

## 1. Does gunzip work?

As per http://nginx.org/r/gunzip, the following text is present in the documentation for the filter:

> Enables or disables decompression of gzipped responses for clients that lack gzip support.

It is not entirely clear whether that the above statement should be construed as the description of the module (e.g., the clients lacking gzip support is why you might want to use this module), or whether it's the description of the behaviour (e.g., whether the module determines by itself whether or not gzip would be supported by the client).  The source code at [src/http/modules/ngx_http_gunzip_filter_module.c](http://ngx.su/src/http/modules/ngx_http_gunzip_filter_module.c#ngx_http_gunzip_header_filter) appears to imply that it simply checks whether the `Content-Encoding` of the reply as-is is `gzip`, and proceed if so.  However, the next sentence in the docs (after the above quoted one) does appear to indicate that it has some more interaction with the `gzip` module, so, perhaps something else is involved as well.

My guess here is that if you're testing with a browser, then the browser DOES support gzip, hence, it would be reasonable for `gunzip` to not engage, hence, the SSI module would never have anything valid to process.  This is why I suggest you determine whether the gunzip works properly and/or differently between doing simple plain-text requests through [`curl`](http://mdoc.su/n/curl) versus those made by the browser with the `Accept-Encoding` that includes `gzip`.

## Solution.

Depending on the outcome of the investigation as above, I would try to determine the order of the modules, and, if incorrect, there's a choice whether recompiling or double-proxying would be the solution.

Subsequently, if the problem is still not fixed, I would ensure that `gunzip` filter would unconditionally do the decompression of the data from [`memcached`](http://mdoc.su/f/memcached); I would imagine you may have to ignore or reset the `Accept-Encoding` headers or some such.

Comment: gunzip works well. Tried to insert the result of memcached + gunzip to a page as SSI fragment. (another way around. In the question -- SSI fragment to memcached + gunzip page). I think, the problem in filter order. But in this case, I can't understand why solution with to servers configs also not works